# How do I get a list of rpms from a baseurl?

Tags: yum

I don't want to install the `.repo` file into my `/etc/yum.repos.d` so I can't use yumdownloader or `yum downloadonly`.

I noticed the `.repo` file contains the baseurl, how do I get a list of urls of the rpms offered there if they don't allow directory listings?

Answer (score 1):

In most situations the url will allow directory listings so give it a try first.

You can use the `repoquery` program offered by the `yum-utils` package.

At first it seems to be for installed repos but a clever use of options and reading the man page will let you do the above. Thanks to #centos for the tip.

For example using the baseurl for the yarnpkg repo, which does not allow directory listings:

```
repoquery --repofrompath="yarndownload,https://dl.yarnpkg.com/rpm" --repoid="yarndownload" --all --location
```

The `yarndownload` here is just a uniqueid for the two parameters, you can make it anything.

Sometimes, as in the case of yarnpkg, they also provide download links to rpms elsewhere (github release page), however sometimes rpms built there are not signed, so there can still be advantage to using the ones from the repo instead.